# kubuntu upgrade 14.04=>16.04 went wrong

Tags: 16.04, plasma

I am facing some issues with kubuntu upgrade recently using kubuntu-devel-release-upgrade from my 14.04 version, though installation finished without any error messages; after machine restart it is just a blank screen. I can see kubuntu in the screen centre while booting and will end up in a blank screen. If I press ctrl+alt+f1 it will allow me to login console and I tried few tips like reinstalling plasma-desktop etc but all in vain. I dont think this is an issue with my display drivers, since same version I tried on another partition and is working fine.

Kindly update if anyone come across similar situation.

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a problem of X. Have a closer look at /var/log/Xorg.0.log with

> sudo less /var/log/Xorg.0.log

and check the content and maybe post it here.

Comment: with X system logs can see " 22.385] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: i965" where for a fresh installation it was "VDPAU driver: va_gl". Also the below lines were different "[    22.127]    X.Org Video Driver: 15.0
[    22.127]    X.Org XInput driver : 20.0
[    22.127]    X.Org Server Extension : 8.0" where for the fresh installation on new partition it was like "X.Org Video Driver: 20.0 and X.Org XInput driver : 22.1". Please note that this I got from the same machine installing on different partitions. Fresh installation is good, upgrade not. Not sure if this make any sense. Thanks.